# Facebook PHP SDK v4 get current accessToken

Tags: php, facebook, session, facebook-access-token, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have no problem getting a FacebookSession with the `getSessionFromRedirect()` function, but I am having a problem returning a token from it.

```
Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(
    Config::get('api/facebook/app_id'), 
    Config::get('api/facebook/app_secret')
);

$fb = new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(Config::get('api/facebook/url'));

if(Session::exists(Config::get('session/facebook'))) {
    //echo Session::get(Config::get('session/facebook'));
    $session = Session::get(Config::get('session/facebook'));
} else {
    $session = $fb->getSessionFromRedirect();
    var_dump($session);
    //Session::put(Config::get('session/facebook'), $session->getToken());
}

if(isset($session)) {

    //Do Facebook stuff here

} else {
    $params = array(
        'scope' => 'email, user_birthday'
    );
    echo "<a href='".$fb->getLoginUrl($params)."'>Login</a>";
}
```

As you can see, I was playing around with the FacebookSession object like `var_dump`ing it but I still can't seem to get a token. I've read the docs and the FacebookSession object has a `getToken()` function but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Here is what I get back after dumping the session

```
object(Facebook\FacebookSession)#9 (2) { ["accessToken":"Facebook\FacebookSession":private]=> object(Facebook\Entities\AccessToken)#4 (3) { ["accessToken":protected]=> string(220) "*INSERT TOKEN HERE, THIS WAS REPLACED FOR THE QUESTION*" ["machineId":protected]=> NULL ["expiresAt":protected]=> NULL } ["signedRequest":"Facebook\FacebookSession":private]=> NULL }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up figuring it out. I already had an init file that ran `session_start()` for me so that wasn't it.

```
Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(
    Config::get('api/facebook/app_id'), 
    Config::get('api/facebook/app_secret')
);

$fb = new Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper(Config::get('api/facebook/url'));

if(Session::exists(Config::get('session/facebook'))) {
    $session = new Facebook\FacebookSession(Session::get(Config::get('session/facebook')));
} else {
    $session = $fb->getSessionFromRedirect();
}

if(isset($session)) {
    if(!Session::exists(Config::get('session/facebook'))) {
        Session::put(Config::get('session/facebook'), $session->getToken());
    }
    //Do Facebook stuff here

} else {
    $params = array(
        'scope' => 'email, user_birthday'
    );
    echo "<a href='".$fb->getLoginUrl($params)."'>Login</a>";
}
```

Because the page didn't refresh, the `$session` variable wasn't a real object yet, I just had to place it once `isset($session)` was called

Answer (score 0):

you have to write session_start on top of your script in order to make it work
so it will be like

```
<?php
session_start();
Facebook\FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(
    Config::get('api/facebook/app_id'), 
    Config::get('api/facebook/app_secret')
);
```

Comment: I actually ended up figuring it out. I already called `session_start()` in an init file so that wasn't it. I just needed to run the function after I made sure the `$session` var was set. Thanks though!